# How to make a flash-animation with a row of pictureboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating the famous "Lingo"- game in C# and WinForm and I'm at the part when the word is correctly guessed. My 'letter game'contains 25 labels and 25 picture boxes (for a 5 letter game) and I would like to animate the current row like in the real tv-game Example [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t91wQ3eg7A&feature=youtu.be&t=213)

I have tried to make a video via MS PowerPoint (succeeded) and play the sound at the background with it. But the video shows up on top of the letters, so those are not visible anymore. But for this I have to make a new video for a new Length of an other game.

After soms Google-ing around, I found that picture editing was possible, so I'm using a part of a found program for the brightness editor for a picture box.

```
        for (int x = 0; x != 5; x++)
        {
            float brightness = 1.0f; // no change in brightness
            float contrast = 1.0f; // twice the contrast
            float gamma = 1.0f; // no change in gamma

            float adjustedBrightness = brightness - 1.0f;
            // create matrix that will brighten and contrast the image
            float[][] ptsArray ={
            new float[] {contrast, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // scale red
            new float[] {0, contrast, 0, 0, 0}, // scale green
            new float[] {0, 0, contrast, 0, 0}, // scale blue
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0}, // don't scale alpha
            new float[] {adjustedBrightness, adjustedBrightness, adjustedBrightness, 0, 1}};

            ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
            imageAttributes.ClearColorMatrix();
            imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(ptsArray), ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
            imageAttributes.SetGamma(gamma, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(v[0, 1].BackgroundImage);
            g.DrawImage(v[0, 1].BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, v[0, 1].BackgroundImage.Width, v[0, 1].BackgroundImage.Height)
                , 0, 0, v[0, 1].BackgroundImage.Width, v[0, 1].BackgroundImage.Height,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
        }
    }
```

[image: See image!]

But the brightness should be applied on all of the 5 current-row picture boxes, but few later AND few later add more brightness to the max and then lower the brightness (for the flash effect). Is there a way to do this in a smooth way / should I use the video option or the above one? Or maybe is WinForm nog suitable for this?

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag should only be used for questions pertaining to the Visual Studio application, not code you write using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the image, you could inherit from PictureBox and draw a semi-transparent white rectangle on top of it:

```
public class FlashingPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    private int flashIntensity;

    public int FlashIntensity
    {
        get
        {
            return flashIntensity;
        }
        set
        {
            if (flashIntensity == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            flashIntensity = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        if (FlashIntensity == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(FlashIntensity, 255, 255, 255)))
        {
            pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

Then set the `FlashIntensity` property to 0..255 to make them light up.

As for the animation, I'd create a separate class that takes the "target" pictureboxes and can compute the desired intensity for each picturebox by the number of milliseconds since the start of the animation.

The following doesn't do *exactly* what you want, but it might give an idea on how to manage the animation in a separate class:

```
public class WinAnimation
{
    private readonly FlashingPictureBox[] boxes;
    private readonly int started;
    const int singleFlashDuration = 700;
    const int nextBoxDelay = 100;
    const int duration = 3000;

    public WinAnimation(params FlashingPictureBox[] boxes)
    {
        this.boxes = boxes;
        started = Environment.TickCount;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the animation at the indicated point in time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="elapsed">The time elapsed since the animation started, in milliseconds</param>
    /// <returns>true if the animation is running, false if the animation is completed</returns>
    public bool Animate()
    {
        int elapsed = Environment.TickCount - started;
        if (elapsed >= duration)
        {
            foreach (var box in boxes)
            {
                box.FlashIntensity = 0;
            }

            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
        {
            var box = boxes[i];
            int boxElapsed = elapsed - i * nextBoxDelay;
            if (boxElapsed < 0)
            {
                box.FlashIntensity = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int intensity = (boxElapsed % singleFlashDuration);
                intensity = (intensity * 255) / singleFlashDuration;
                box.FlashIntensity = intensity;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can call this from your form as follows, assuming you have a timer:

```
    private WinAnimation ani; // the animation object

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ani = new WinAnimation(flashingPictureBox1, flashingPictureBox2, flashingPictureBox3, flashingPictureBox4, flashingPictureBox5);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ani.Animate())
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            ani = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So for the clear view in my code, I combined the squares with the backgrounds. I've created a TableLayoutPanel[,] vakjes = new TableLayoutPanel[5, 5] and called every square v1 - v25

Comment: Always a good idea to put them in an array rather than individually named controls - but I don't know if you meant to ask something in that comment?

Comment: I did this beforehand and I have 2 int's to acces the 'coordinates' in the Array. Current_line and Current_letter. Smart?

Comment: Definitely smart to be able to access controls by coordinates that way, compared to using individually named controls.

Comment: And I've a scoring part in the game, and how should I call this to start?

Comment: I assume your application already detects when someone has guessed the right word? That's when you could start a timer. Each time it ticks you tell the animation to proceed, until it is done and you stop the timer. Remeber this is just an example to give you an idea on how to approach this.

Comment: Yes, I'm checking a number of 1's in an array, So Timer.Start wil do the trick?

Comment: The only thing that's left now is to add the v1 until v5, but those are not recognized in <code> ani = new WinAnimation(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5); and then I could check if there is something flashing</code>

Comment: Have you changed their type from `PictureBox` to `FlashingPictureBox`?

Comment: None of those are they? I think I missed something. 
TBH: This base game I've currently now, did this in 5 years. Almost 0 knowledge of programming but Piece bij piece....

Comment: BTW: Does this take effect on the fact that I use the Array also for coloring the pictureboxes?

Comment: I just saw that i Don't have PB's but TableLayoutPanel's. Does that change?